# I show trivial topolgies is smallest and discrete topology is the largest topology of any set X

Tags: general-topology

show that the trivial topology $\mathcal{T}_1$  is the smalletes topologies for any set $X$ and the discrete topology $\mathcal{T}_2$ is the largest topology for any set X

---

for **trivial topology** $\mathcal{T}_1=\{ \emptyset , X\}$

I think by the meaning of smallest is the smallest amount of elements of $\mathcal{T}$. So for the trivial topology take any then it would not be a topology.

**for the discrete topology**  being the largest

would have to assume there is a largest topology and somehow derive that there is a contradiction

do know the definition of the discrete topology any subset of $X$ is open

*completely lost here could use help*

Comment: angryavian's answer is just fine, but I think this is a problem that would have been tackled more easily if you picked a sample set of (say) five items, and constructed the trivial and discrete topologies on it, and then picked other topologies as well.  Concrete examples help a lot!  Either you would have gotten the answer, or you would not, but you would have been able to add more to the question.

Comment: had not realized what the largest or smallest means to begin with.  also all i had to go with is that  discrete topology is generated by discrete metric. In the discrete topology, every subset X is open. I did not know that in the discrete topology consists of all subsets of X. Yeah, Ill go over concrete examples. I seen one here somewhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, a topology must contain the empty set and $X$, so the trivial topology is a subset of any topology.

By definition a topology consists of subsets of $X$. The discrete topology consists of *all* subsets of $X$, and therefore any topology is a subset of the discrete topology.